# « Envoye Ti-Caille » dans une chanson de Richard Desjardins ?

Tags: étymologie, québec, paroles-de-chanson

L'album de [Richard Desjardins](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Desjardins), [*Tu m'aimes-tu*](http://www.richarddesjardins.com/musicographie/albums/tu-maimes-tu.html) (1990) contient la chanson *L'homme-canon* dont voici les deux premiers couplets:

> Vendu l'prélart
>   Cassé mon baïl
>   Rendu dehors
>   Chien pas d'médaille
>   Un p'tit effort
>   **Envoye Ti-Caille**
>
> Ma poignée d'change
>   Brille dans la nuit
>   Comme un p'tit ange
>   Au pied du lit
>   Un signe de chance
>   Peut-être que oui
>
> [ retranscription d'origine incertaine d'un extrait de *L'homme-canon*, de Richard Desjardins ]

La [*caille*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caille) désigne normalement un *[p]etit oiseau migrateur au plumage brun tacheté*.

Qu'est-ce que signifie le « ti-caille » ici ? Quelle est l'origine de cette expression ?

Comment: Not sure enough about any of this to put it as an answer, but I’d have guessed “Envoyé au (petit) froid” from “ca caille” or even “Envoyé au [Lac Ti-Caille"](http://travelingluck.com/North+America/Canada/Quebec/_6044691_Lac+Ti-Caille.html)
 (where I imagine it’s cold !), BUT THEN I found the following:(to be continued)...:

Comment: (must be cached,can’t find it on th/site):[Quant au nom Ti-Caille, il représente quelqu'un dont le cerveau est exposé au crétinisme léger, dû à un " écalage " qui entraîne un certain " décalage ".](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A0LEVvRUiuJUDiIAKasnnIlQ;_ylc=X1MDMTM1MTE5NTY4NwRfcgMyBGZyA3locy1tb3ppbGxhLTAwMQRncHJpZAN5V3p0STRtT1IxYVV5RzFjYWZvSjhBBG5fcnNsdAMwBG5fc3VnZwM0BG9yaWdpbgNzZWFyY2gueWFob28uY29tBHBvcwMwBHBxc3RyAwRwcXN0cmwDBHFzdHJsAzI0BHF1ZXJ5AyJRdWFudCBhdSBub20gVGktQ2FpbGxlIgR0X3N0bXADMTQyNDEzMjcxNg--?p=%22Quant+au+nom+Ti-Caille%22&fr2=sb-top-search&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-001)

Comment: Hopefully that can give you or someone else out there an idea from which to "continue" the search (or plutot from which to start it in earnest). (BTW there's an accent in envoyé, I think, if that makes a difference)

Comment: @PapaPoule: *Caille* is also an affectionate nickname, usually given to a young girl, but could be understood used for any young person. And *ti* is common in several French créoles for *petit*.

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks! Indeed it's hard to find a formal definition from a more established source... there is also context clearly. For the accent, no, it's really the imperative with the singular form, I listened to the song, there is no doubt in my mind. The accent is all over the web, this just goes to show how lyrics site blatantly rip off from one another lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Au Québec, «Ti-Caille» est un surnom qu'on donne à quelqu'un d'autre. Il n'est pas, à ma connaissance, péjoratif. Il me semble que j'appellerais «Ti-Caille» quelqu'un qui est plus jeune que moi, un garçon ou un adolescent, à la limite un homme dans la vingtaine. Dans la chanson de Desjardins, j'ai l'impression que c'est lui-même qui se nomme Ti-Caille; il s'encourage à faire quelque chose.

Comment: Merci!  Ça me laisse une impression similaire ici de sorte que je suis plutôt d'accord avec la réponse. Mais est-ce qu'on a une référence ou une définition écrite; sur quoi reposent ces impressions. Et a-t-on une idée de l'origine de l'expression?

Answer (score 2):

Un complément. Un sens plus régional pour [*caille*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caille) c'est sans doute la couleur (de la caille - *brun tacheté*).

> [Câille](https://archive.org/stream/leparlerpopulair00dionuoft#page/114/mode/2up) adj.
>  
>   Mélange de blanc et de noir. ex. Marie, va *tirer* la grande vache
>   *câille*. Thérèse a les yeux *câilles*.
>   [ *Le parler populaire des Canadiens Français*, N.-E. Dionne, 1909 ]
>
> [Câille](https://archive.org/stream/fre_b2079207#page/n107/mode/2up) adj.
>  
>   Se dit des taches irrégulières, noires et blanches ou blanches et
>   rousses, de la robe des cheveaux, boeufs, vaches, etc., et aussi du
>   plumage des poules: -une vache *câille*, une poule *câille*.
>   [ *Dictionnaire Canadien-Français*, Sylva Clapin, 1894 ]
>
> [Câille](https://archive.org/stream/cihm_02800#page/n65/mode/2up) adj. Nor[mand]. Blanc et couleur foncée. "Une vache câille".
>  
>   [ *Glossaire franco-canadien*, Oscar Dunn, 1880 ]

Dans la chanson c'est une forme de générique - [quelqu'un d'autre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13150/3177) avec certaines caractéristiques en effet, comme le valet de trèfle, peut-être aux *cheveux bruns* à l'origine - c'est une théorie. Dans un contexte comme la toponymie au Québec, il y a bien des références [idiosyncratiques](https://books.google.ca/books?id=MLChUpf_66EC&lpg=PA561&dq=%22ti%20caille%22&pg=PA562#v=onepage&q=%22ti%20caille%22&f=false) qui sont parfois au final ancrées dans des trucs très concrets; peut-être que c'est similaire ici. C'est aussi dans d'autres contextes parfois quelqu'un de pris au dépourvu ou littéralement dépourvu pourrait-on dire. Utilisé seul pour interpeller quelqu'un qui ne nous est pas familier, ce peut être condescendant sans que pour autant ce soit nécessairement péjoratif. Enfin, dans le [*Petit guide du parler québécois*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=73hcAAAAMAAJ&q=ti-caille%20qu%C3%A9bec&dq=ti-caille%20qu%C3%A9bec&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kqnqVMqUCIiuggTH24C4Dw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBA) de M. Mario Bélanger, celui-ci produit une liste de termes avec des nuances - dont *tarla*, *épais*, *ti-casse*, *ti-cul*, *ti-coune*, *deux de pique* etc. et *ti-caille*, puis indique(fragments vu les droits, donc aucun contexte):

> Termes pour se moquer d'une personne. Le ti est diminutif pour « petit
>   ».