# Le « brasse-camarade » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, régionalismes, dictionnaires

Dans un [article](http://www.lapresse.ca/arts/livres/201609/13/01-5019955-les-dicos-de-la-rentree.php) on parle des dictionnaires de la rentrée et on mentionne que certains régionalismes, du Québec ou du Canada faut-il comprendre, font leur entrée soit au Robert (*relationniste*, *plate* et *massothérapeute*) ou au Larousse (***[brasse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brasser)-[camarade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/camarade)***, *(dé)zipper* et *conventum*). Le *GDT* atteste il y a plus de 30 ans le terme comme généralité, au Canada, et donne une définition un peu particulière :

> Décrit l'impression qui se dégage d'une réunion, le climat qui précède
>   la bagarre.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique, GDT, [brasse-camarade](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17566704) ]

Le *Wiktionnaire* a une bonne [ébauche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasse-camarade) sur le sujet et identifie deux sens : le *remue-ménage* et la *réorganisation/restructuration*. Pour le premier sens un donne comme exemple :

> Rien de tel qu'un peu de brasse-camarade en fin de troisième période
>   pour mettre la table à un septième match des séries de la LNH.
>
> [ [*Ça brasse en fin de match!*](http://www.tvasports.ca/2014/05/12/ca-brasse-en-fin-de-match), tva sports, extrait présenté au
>   *Wiktionnaire* à *brasse-camarade*. ]

Dans le texte on parle d'une [*escarmouche*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/escarmouche/30954?q=escarmouche#30866) ; il y a des nuances de sens et d'emploi de termes similaires comme le [*grabuge*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/grabuge/37720?q=grabuge#37667), l'[*altercation*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/altercation/2552?q=altercation#2550), l'[*accrochage*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/accrochage/548) ou l'[*échauffourée*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9chauffour%C3%A9e/27438), mais le *remue-ménage*, par extension, c'est le *chahut*, la *pagaille*, et au figuré c'est surtout l'*agitation confuse ou l'état de tension* (TLFi), quoiqu'on semble associer la [*bousculade*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bousculade/10715) à cette fébrilité. Pour le sens de restructuration, on donne comme exemple :

> Dans le domaine de la santé, je me souviens qu'à l'époque on avait
>   reçu le ministre fédéral de la Santé à la régie régionale où j'étais.
>   Il avait dit: «On vous demande de faire votre brasse-camarade. On vous
>   demande de faire votre ménage, mais pour quelques années seulement, le
>   temps qu'on remette de l'ordre dans le système de santé.
>
> [ [Mme Diane Bourgeois](http://www.parl.gc.ca/HousePublications/Publication.aspx?DocId=1385106&Language=F&Mode=1&Parl=37&Ses=1#Int-172315), ayant représenté la circonscription de Terrebonne—Blainville au Parlement du Canada, en 2002, extrait présenté au
>   Wiktionnaire à *brasse-camarade* ]

Le réorganisation/restructuration n'est qu'un des sens possibles ici et pas nécessairement celui qui vienne à l'esprit au premier coup d’œil à mon avis.

---

- Connaît-on l'origine précise du « brasse-camarade » (qui, quand et où) ?
- Quel(s) est/sont le(s) sens du « brasse-camarade » ; comment sont-ils reliés et de quel(s) type(s) de sens s'agit-il le cas échéant ?
- *Du remue-ménage* est-il communément utilisé (ailleurs
  qu'au Québec/Canada) pour décrire une situation comme celle de
  l'exemple de *tva sports* (hockey) ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "brasse-camarade" en France. Par contre, "remue-ménage" est courant, qui peut être synonyme de "foutoir" ou "bordel" pour indiquer du bruit et/ou de l'agitation inhabituelle, sans connotation négative...

Comment: En France, "Camarade" n'est utilisé que dans 2 contextes: 1. à l'école, quand on parle d'un "camarade de classe", la connotation est neutre, c'est tout simplement quelqu'un de la même classe. 2. Quand on fait référence à la Russie (plus particulièrement au communisme), où "camarade" fait référence à n'importe quelle personne communiste (considérée comme "proche" car communiste également).

Comment: @PapaPoule The couple _shake-up_ and _standoff_, that's really an interesting way of exploring the sort of things I discuss from a sort of comparative angle. It can also be tricky. But consider this, I've found in this _Franco-Américain_ mag.from '49 the following : "Ce demler était fort connu dans tous les milieux franco-américains; il était un brasse- camarade invétéré, et il avait une faconde à tout casser." ([Le Phare](https://books.google.com/books?id=3TwoAAAAMAAJ&dq=Le+Phare%3A+le+magazine+des+Franco-Am%C3%A9ricains%2C+Volume+2&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=brasse)). OCR err, still inter.

Comment: Avec celui-ci une promesse cassée mais seulement pour dire que mes autres commentaires sont retirés et que je bosse sur une espèce de réponse!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je suis Québécois, et je crois que le sens de base est *bagarre*, *échauffourée*, du moins tel que je le conçois. À partir de ce sens, on passe directement à *remue-ménage, bousculade* par litote. Comprendre qu'on est encore ici dans la description d'une situation *matérielle* avec de *possibles conséquences physiques*: objet renversés, chutes, ecchymoses, égratignures... Toutefois, il est parfaitement plausible que le glissement se soit fait dans l'autre sens, par hyperbole. Ce sont dans l'un et l'autre cas des extensions de sens parfaitement naturelles et très communes.

Par contre, je doute fort que *brasse-camarade* puisse être défini en tant que tel comme une "réorganisation". Il me semble très clair, au contraire, que **Mme Bourgeois applique une figure de style à la réorganisation qu'on exigea à l'époque**. C'est-à-dire qu'elle fait allusion non à la réorganisation en elle-même mais au chaos qui l'entoure (chaos notoire dans quasiment toutes les réorganisations du système de santé québécois) et aux efforts des nombreux intervenants pour ne pas voir leurs postes supprimés ou financements réduits, assimilés ici à la métaphore d'une bagarre.

D'ailleurs, le *Dictionnaire Québécois d'Aujourd'hui* (1992) donne comme définition du mot "Vive discussion" (ajoutant même "grosse engueulade"), une autre litote à partir du sens de "bagarre, échauffourée" et qui me semble aussi parfaitement approprié à l'usage de Mme Bourgeois.

Comment: Je n'ai pas d'information étymologique. Il n'existe tout simplement pas de source comparable au TLFi (Trésor de la langue française informatisée) pour le français Canadian/Québécois pour se référer dans ce genre de cas. Les références sont excessivement fragmentaire et généralement concentrées sur un petit nombre de termes. Quand à la définition du GDT, elle est complètement inutile. Ce n'est pas une définition du sens de ce mot autant qu'une bien mauvaise description de la métaphore qu'il exprime.

Comment: Je ne serait pas autrement surpris si à l'origine l'expression était en rapport avec le sport (pas nécessairement le hockey, d'ailleurs), mais c'est de la pure spéculation de ma part.

Answer (score 4):

This question, which I'd certainly characterize as a higher level thinking question, has led me in endless circles, on dead-end tangents, and finally, to
the conclusion that I lack the kind of higher order thinking skills required to fully answer it.

This is evidenced by the fact that, concerning the meaning of *brasse-camarade*, I have previously formulated many conflicting opinions, including one opinion/"answer” concentrating on the English notion of “movement”; then a second on that of “confrontation” (both of which are re-posted below in reverse order); and now (but certainly not finally) a third:

Although generally relevant as it stands, I now feel that (in both English and French) “confrontation” is lacking something and should be narrowed, especially in political contexts, to capture the notion of "confrontations between members of a group," which is captured well, I think, in English by *The American Heritage Dictionary’s* first, slightly figurative meaning of [“in[-]fighting”](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=infighting):

> “1. Contentious rivalry or disagreement among members of a group or
>   organization: infighting on the President's staff.” …

… which in turn, according to some examples from *Reverso Context*, could be translated as [“querelle/lutte/conflit  intestine/interne”](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/in-fighting) and to the figurative extreme, perhaps even as *lutte fratricide* as I believe Honoré Mercier was using it in his memorable words:  [«Cessons nos luttes fratricides! Unissons-nous!»](http://delbussoediteur.ca/publications/honore-mercier-discours-1873-1893/)
(from *Delbusso Editeur*)

Although probably totally coincidental, it is perhaps interesting to note that even the more literal meaning of *infighting* in English (i.e., “2. Fighting or boxing at close range” = “close combat” = [“corps-à-corps?](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/corps-%C3%A0-corps)) could be seen as corresponding a bit with “brasse-camarade” when used  in contexts involving actual contact, as in hockey, and to the extent that *corps-à-corps* is a valid translation,  somewhat with the important notion of “[à] bras-le-corps” discussed [in this good answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21946/le-brasse-camarade/22040#22040).

Finally, regarding possible origins of the term at issue and/or possible explanations of its attributive use in *Le Phare*, please see my thoughts on those points scattered throughout below.
(cf: possible translations of the noun "infighter," including, from *Word Forum*, [*ennemi intérieur*](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/infighter), which I don't particularly like in the *Le Phare* context, or in any context for that matter)

---

(**original answer as first posted** [with some of its grammar mistakes corrected])

In spite of all the notions and suggestions found **way** below ... ,

(in what was originally designed to be my answer, but which I’m keeping nonetheless because of some overlapping cross references (and NOT as it might appear, just to make this a longer and harder read than it needs to be because that ship sailed long ago with just this new “answer”)

... upon further reflection, I think the best single-word noun that could replace *brasse-camarade* in both of the question’s particular examples would be [*confrontation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/confrontation) in *CNRTL*’s sense # B(3)(c):

> “À l'idée de face à face s'ajoute celle d'affrontement (another
>   possibility?), d'antagonisme, de conflit; …,”

which is the French sense that most closely resembles the meaning that I most often associate with that word in English:

“Rien de tel qu'un peu de confrontation en fin … .”

“On vous demande de faire votre confrontation [avec vos membres].”
(although like «faire votre brasse-camarade» (see way below) the *votre* seems weird to me and either:
 “On vous demande de faire **une/la** confrontation » or
“On vous demande de confronter vos [membres]”
 would probably be more idiomatic)

For the use of « brasse-camarade » as a noun representing a person with [a] certain characteristic/s, such as in « Il était un brasse-camarade invétéré » from *Le Phare* and mentioned in the comments, “confronter,” “confrontationalist,” and even “confrontationist” exist as nouns in English to describe “a confrontational man/fellow.”

In French, however, such attributive forms (*confrontat/aire/eur/rice* or *confrontation[nel]iste*)  don’t seem to exist and even if *un homme confrontationnel* or *homme de confrontation* might be understood in French, the fact that they get respectively zero and only [10 hits on *google.com*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+was+confrontation+personified%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22un+homme+de+confrontation%22) is perhaps good evidence that it’s just a notion and construction that’s been borrowed from English.

So for a suggestion somewhat related to *confrontation* for that attributive usage in *Le Phare*, looking back to *CNRTL*’s sense # B(3)(c) for *confrontation*,  there’s “the idea of *antagonisme*,” which could lead to [*antagoniste*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/antagoniste) (also from *CNRTL*).

However, even though it doesn’t totally jive with my *confrontation* theme and theory (and without knowing the full context of the description from *Le phare*), I think [*agitateur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agitateur) would be even better, i.e.:

> “Personne qui crée des troubles, le plus souvent à des fins
>   politiques, sociales ou révolutionnaires”

also from *CNRTL*
 (note also the word’s connection with the beer brewing/*brasserie* industry, which makes me wonder now if [*agitation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agitation) (mentioned in the question and in a “Random”  comment directly under it)  wouldn’t be better than *confrontation* in ALL the contexts, but it’s too late for that for this great question has already sent me on too many tangents and exploring *agitation* any further would probably just give rise to several more to pursue!)

Regarding possible origins, the similarities mentioned [still] way below between *brasse-Canayen* and *brasse-camarade* at first led me to feel that perhaps *camarade* at some point began replacing *Canayen* because the former was seen as a less offensive way to refer to oneself and to one’s fellow sufferers of such treatment (being shaken/pushed around).

However, being unable to find any indication that *Canayen* is/was considered to be offensive, I considered the following possible reasons (all pure conjecture) for what I still believe could be an instance of replacing/shifting from one word (*Canayen* in this case) with/to another one (i.e.,*camarade*):

1)  To create an expression that would be more universally **applicable** (not just to contexts involving French Canadians and somewhat more universally **understandable** (to the extent that at least knowing the meaning of *Canayen* would not be required to understand it).

2)  To create an expression that would avoid using an arguably *joual* term (especially one like *Canayen* that meant/means “Canadian French”), which could be seen as consistent with  «La Révolution tranquille et le joual emballe, 1960-70» described (as I interpret it) in Chapter 9 of Chantal Bouchard’s *La langue et le nombril: une histoire sociolinguistique du Québec* as a pivotal moment when a renewed pride in the nature of their French caused the people of Québec to move away from *joual*, which over the years had become, perhaps wrongly, synonymous with *la langue canadienne-française* (especially when called *canayen*) and move toward being proud Francophones speaking *Québécois* (not to mention that this also permitted them to avoid using the word *canadien* or even a corrupted version thereof, when referring to their language and to their fellow Québécois, i.e., their fellow *camarades*).

Alas, the appearance of “brasse-camarade” used attributively  in *Le Phare* pre-dates the *Révolution tranquille* mentioned above by at least 10 years, so there’s another tangent pursued in vain, but as mentioned in a comment, this particular early use could possibly be borrowed from the English “brass fellow” with *camarade* being a reasonable substitute for “fellow.”
Or perhaps even a transformed borrowing of the hyphenated adjective “brass-knuckle [tactics]” for use as a noun.
(cf [this rather clever name](http://www.brasskamarades.com/histoire.html) for a brass quintet from the ensemble’s website)

If such borrowing does explain the usage in *Le Phare* it could certainly be seen as the precise origin of the term as it’s used today, but if it was a one-time, unrelated act of borrowing, the *Révolution tranquille* angle could at least help explain any accelerated use of the term that followed that revolution.

(for possible further tangents to pursue (or with which to question my “conclusions!), see this interesting juxtaposition of [“des **prises de bec**, des **différends**, [and] des **brasse-camarades**”](http://www.belfortho.fr/fs/Root/d1byt-Dictee1.pdf) in  paragraph 2 of a *Le Robert* dictation exercise and the last *commentaire des difficultés* on the bottom of page 2 found at *belfortho.fr*;

(as well as the following Google hits for the term’s two plural forms: [“brasse-camaradeS”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brasses-camarades%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22brasse-camarades%22) and the questionable, yet more popular [“brasseS-camaradeS”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brasses-camarades%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8);

(and finally [here](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10153403834356710&id=298153161709&tra=1&__tn__=%2As&_rdr) for what appears to be *Larousses*’s official entry (including the plural) for *brasse-camarade* from a somewhat random looking *Facebook* “page.”)

(end of "new" answer)

---

(**heretofore un-posted original answer below**)

In light of their similar hyphenated structures (“brasse+[-a noun that could be seen as representing a compatriot or a sympathetic fellow member of a group]") and the identical use of “remue-ménage” in both [this *Quia* entry for “Brasse-Canayen”](https://www.quia.com/jg/1663571list.html) and in the [one cited in the question from *Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasse-camarade) (#1) for “Brasse-camarade,” I’m tempted to conclude that the meaning of the two terms is identical and that examining the uses and meaning of one can help explain the other.

Further evidence of a connection between the two terms is that they both have variations expressed in identical forms having identical meanings, to wit:
[se faire brasser **le camarade**](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g499300-d185018-i109062458-Canada_s_Wonderland-Vaughan_Ontario.html) from a *Trip Advisor* review of a roller-coaster ride
and [se faire brasser **le canayen**](http://isamatte.blogspot.com/2012_03_01_archive.html) from Isa’s *Blogspot* description of similar amusement park rides.

Both of the above usage examples are, in my eyes, describing the same movement and motion, i.e., a physical shaking/jostling or the feeling of being literally shaken/jostled about from left to right, just as, according to my interpretation of the entry under “barouette” on *Angelfire.com*, [“se faire brasser”](http://www.angelfire.com/pq/lexique/lexique.html) all alone would mean.

All that to say that I feel that both of these hyphenated expressions (and especially their “se faire brasser” variations) are based on the literal sense of the notions of movement and motion in general and, in particular, movements/motions that would be described (in English) as “jostling” or “shaking” (and in spite of James Bond’s preference re martinis, perhaps even “stirring”!)

Therefore finding their meanings (in English) when encountering them (especially the hyphenated versions) used figuratively in French requires, for me at least, finding relevant figurative English uses of “jostling” (e.g., “jostling for position”) and/or “shaking/stirring (e.g., “shaking/stirring things up”) (or even just “a shake-up,” but see below) and then finding possible French equivalents for them.

“Jostle/jostling for position” could lead in French to “bousculade” (mentioned in the question) or from *Reverso*, [“jouer des coudes”](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/to%20jostle%20for%20position), which I think could fit both figuratively (maneuvering to gain an advantage) and literally (throwing elbows) in the hockey example:

> “Rien de tel que de jouer des coudes un peu en fin … .”

Granted, the notion is being proposed as a verbal phrase because I’ve found little or no instances of its use as a noun (i.e., “ Rien de tel qu'un petit jeu des coudes en fin… . ”)

Using *Reverso*’s “context” tool, [“Shake/shaking [things] up [a bit]”](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=shake+things+up+a+bit&langFrom=en&langTo=fr&langTot=en-fr) as a verb led me to 4 instances of *secouer [un peu] les choses* as a verbal phrase and one instance where the phrase is used with the verb “remuer” (as in *le remue-ménage*).

As for *Reverso*’s entry for “stir things up” [(= *donner un coup de pied dans la fourmilière*)](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/stir%20things%20up), perhaps 007’s preference is a bit too strong, but then again it, along with all of the verbal phrases mentioned above, could work well enough in many political contexts:

> “On vous demande de donner un coup de pied dans la fourmilière.”
>   “On vous demande de secouer/remuer [un peu] les choses.”

or even

> “On vous demande de jouer des coudes (figurativement).”

On the other hand, *Reverso*’s entry for “Shake-up” as an English noun could lead to *[grande?] reorganization,* which seemingly corresponds with *Wiktionnaire*’s 2nd meaning for the term at issue, but the inclusion of *grande* conflicts with my understanding of the extent of changes made during a “shake-up” in English (and during a *brasse-camarade* in French) leading me to conclude that perhaps *reorganization*, especially in light of the curious ***votre*** reorganization that would result, is not appropriate in the particular political context mentioned in the question.

(end of old/original answer and with it the end of this entire[ly too long] post)

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Merci beaucoup! Alors là, non! C’est sur et promis que même pour une autre très (voire trop) généreuse récompense  je n’y rajouterai plus rien, mais même sans une autre récompense offerte, cette question va continuer à me faire travailler la tête pendant un bon bout de temps, ça c’est sur aussi!

Answer (score 2):

On a [traité](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/21954) ailleurs de la composante fondamentale impliquant la *bagarre* et d'extensions de sens, et d'autre part [passé](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/22037) en revue différentes hypothèses et associations avec des termes similaires. Ici on dresse un parallèle entre le *brasse-camarade* et la locution adverbiale *à bras-le-corps*.

---

Le *Glossaire du parler français du Canada* (1930) ne contient pas d'entrée *camarade* mais on retrouve les locutions adverbiales ***à brasse-[caille](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13149)*** et ***à brasse-corps***, toutes deux dans le sens d'*à bras-le-corps* (et qui me sont inconnues). Quant à *brasser*, il a à cette époque-là à peu près tous les sens imaginables, semble-t-il. Par ailleurs on a aussi un verbe comme *bardasser* pour *secouer*. C'est donc dire qu'on est familier avec des locutions adverbiales à l'allure un peu figée, dont le premier terme est *(à) brasse-* et qui sont presque exclusivement employées avec le verbe *prendre*.

[image]
<sup>[*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), , éd. *L'action sociale*, **1930**, pp. 112, 149-150 (extraits)</sup>

---

C'est que l'ancien prendre ***a brache de corps*** a connu une série de transformations où il a déjà été relié à *brasser* comme verbe avant d'être transposé en *à bras-le-corps*. Pendant un certain temps, la locution avec *brasse* a été productive, puis l'est restée seulement de manière régionale (dont au Québec ; voir aussi *LBU14* §965H6), alors que généralement l'idée d'*à deux bras* a été évacuée du sens moderne de *brasser*, malgré l'influence ; mais on la reconnaît dans la nage ([*brasse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/brasse)-...) etc. Au *TLFi*, on présente une explication sur le sujet et des exemples :

> Quelquefois je la prends, je la tiens à brasse-corps contre moi pour
>   la réchauffer.
>
> (Daudet, [L'Évangéliste](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99%C3%89vang%C3%A9liste), 1883)
>
> ...il marcha auprez dudit Mahiot, et le print à brache de corps, et
>   tellement qu'il le rua par terre soubz lui, où il lui fit grant
>   martire...
>
> (Escouchy, [Chronique de Mathieu d'Escouchy](https://books.google.com/books?id=sPA-AAAAcAAJ&dq=ESCOUCHY%2C%20Chronique&pg=PA304#v=onepage&q=brache&f=false), 1465, ed. marquis de Beaucourt, 1863 )
>
> La forme la plus ancienne de cette locution adverbiale semble avoir
>   été *a brace de corps* ([*a brache de corps*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/brasse?idf=dmfXgXrmXbfag;str=0)), composée de la
>   préposition [*à*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) (= « avec » en ancien français, *cf*. Sneyders, [*Syntaxe historique du français*](https://archive.org/stream/syntaxehistoriq00vogegoog#page/n319/mode/2up), p.
>   306), *brace* « les deux bras » ([*brasse*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXrmXbfag;ISIS=isis_dmf2015.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s08070104;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;XXX=4;;)), [*de*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) (= « quant
>   à, en ce qui concerne » en ancien français, Gamillscheg, [*Historische
>   französische Syntax*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=k4M0AQAAIAAJ&dq=Historische%20franz%C3%B6sische%20Syntax&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=265%20betreffs), p. 265), [*corps*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corps) désignant le corps du
>   partenaire ou des deux vis-à-vis (cf. a. fr. [*s'*]*encontrer de cors
>   et de pis* dans *Tobler-Lommatzsch: Altfranzösisches Wörterbuch*, s.v. [*cors*](http://www.uni-stuttgart.de/lingrom/stein/tl/downloadsf.htm), pp. 903-904 [réf. entre
>   autres *Richars li Biaus*, 13<sup>e</sup> s., voir [ici](https://archive.org/stream/richarslibiausz00unkngoog#page/n71/mode/2up/search/%22cors+et+de+pis%22) et [là](https://archive.org/stream/richarslibiausz00unkngoog#page/n169/mode/2up/search/%22cors+le+pis%22)]). − Une
>   variante de cette locution est *à bras de corps* qui est peut-être
>   issu du croisement de deux locutions : *(prendre) à bras*, « (prendre) avec
>   ses bras » (*Roland*, éd. J. Bédier, [2552](https://archive.org/stream/lachansonderolan00bduoft#page/194/mode/2up)) *de corps* « par le
>   corps » (*cf*. ancien français *de corps et de pis* « au corps à corps
>   » et la locution angevine *se prendre de corps* « avoir une querelle »
>   dans *FEW* t. 2, 2, p. 1212b, s.v. [*corpus*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/62227)). La disparition dans
>   l'usage courant de *brace* au sens de « les deux bras » ([*brasse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/brasse?idf=dmfXgXrmXbfag;str=0)) ainsi
>   que celle de la préposition *de* au sens de « quant à » a abouti à la
>   transformation de la locution primitive : *brasse* a été interprété
>   comme forme verbale (issue de *brasser* au sens ancien et encore
>   dialectal. « entourer de ses bras », *FEW* t. 1, p. 487a, s.v.
>   [*brachium*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/40147)) et *corps* comme objet direct, d'où *à brasse-corps*, sur
>   le modèle d'expression du type *à tire-larigot*, *à tue-tête*, *à
>   brûle-pourpoint*. [*Brasser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brasser) perdant (sauf dans certains dial.,
>   cf. *FEW* t. 1, p. [488b](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/40106)) le sens de « entourer de ses bras »,
>   brasse a été interprété comme *bras + se*, ce dernier, devenu
>   incompréhensible, étant ,,correctement`` remplacé par l'article *le*
>   appelé par le substantif *corps*; l'expression, tout en conservant
>   ainsi son rythme quadrisyllabique, a valeur de syntagme elliptique
>   s'interprétant analytiquement par « prendre qqn [ou qqc.] avec ses
>   bras à soi en lui saisissant le corps », ce qui est conforme pour
>   l'essentiel au sens le plus ancien de l'expression.
>
> [ *Trésor informatisé de la langue française*, TLFi,
>   [*bras-le-corps*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bras-le-corps) (modifié avec abréviations/auteurs étendus et
>   liens vers diverses sources, ainsi que l'ajout d'une remarque sur  *Richars li Biaus*) ]

---

Je crois personnellement que le *brasse-camarade* est une **substantivation de la locution adverbiale** *à bras-le-corps/à brasse-corps*, qui intègre le verbe (prendre) et l'objet (la personne, [originalement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/camarade), surtout en contexte militaire « qui fait ou subit qqc. avec et comme une autre personne ») ; c'est davantage elliptique mais d'usage plus restreint au propre que le *à brasse-corps*. Et ça s'analyserait comme le fait de « prendre le camarade avec ses bras à soi en lui saisissant le corps (ou par métonymie, le camarade) ». Il s'agirait *du à brasse-corps*, avec un adversaire, autrement dit d'une [empoigne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/empoigne), et non de (le) *secouer*, appuyant ainsi le sens de *lutte/bagarre/combat/conflit*, omniprésent.

Au figuré ça resterait surtout la métaphore de la *bagarre*, du *combat* ; ou autrement c'est là que se manifesteraient d'autres apports, tels ceux des autres sens du verbe *brasser*, incluant les plus modernes. Le changement d'interprétation de la locution et ces autres apports masqueraient d'une certaine manière la nature de cette création et contribueraient à l'association au *remue-ménage*, plutôt inadéquat, à mon avis. Mais hormis l'utilité d'avoir une version de *à brasse-corps* substantivée avec une polarité (la variété d'*Escouchy* pour ainsi dire), on [ne connaît pas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brasse-camarade%2Cbrasse-corps%2Cbrasse%20corps%2C%C3%A0%20brasse%20corps%2C%C3%A0%20bras%20le%20*%2Cbras%20le%20*%2C*_VERB%20le%20camarade%2C*_NOUN%20camarade%2C*_VERB%20camarade%2Cbrasse%20*_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) ([2](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bras%20d%27airain,%20de%20fer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZRPiV5mWM8bNjwTpy7j4Cg#q=%22brasse-camarade%22&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&start=100)) l'origine exacte, après 1930 assurément, du nom *brasse-camarade*, même si on a discuté ailleurs de glissements possibles à partir d'autres mots.

Comment: +1! Your pointing out the importance of *empoigne* in the sense of *lutte* reminded me of Honoré Mercier’s stirring figurative use of “luttes fratricides” in 1889: [«Cessons nos luttes fratricides! Unissons-nous!»](http://delbussoediteur.ca/publications/honore-mercier-discours-1873-1893/). To the extent that [the 2 may be similar in meaning](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1250&dat=19780602&id=Z2YdAAAAIBAJ&sjid=iF0EAAAAIBAJ&pg=2900,3928128&hl=en) I’m glad the term at issue appeared after Mercier’s time for I doubt if «Cessons nos brasse-camarades» would've had the same memorable punch!