# "brasser" (dans le sens de mélanger) est-il familier?

Tags: usage, verbes, argot

J'ai toujours utilisé le verbe `brasser` dans le sens de `mélanger`, par exemple :

```
J'ai mis de la sauce dans mes pâtes, je vais les brasser un peu
```

ou

```
Pour obtenir un bon goût il faut bien brasser la vinaigrette.
```

J'ai néanmoins entendu d'une ou deux personnes (de plus de 40 ans, si cela a une importance) que `brasser` a pour sens premier le mouvement de bras (appelé `brasse`) ou le brassage des alcools (cidre, bière) et que le sens `mélanger` est un sens familier indiquant un faible niveau d'éducation.

Que ne fut donc pas ma déconfiture, d'apprendre ainsi que j'ai utilisé ce verbe comme ça pendant tout ce temps.

Le problème, c'est que j'entends ce verbe de la bouche d'un nombre non négligeable de personnes pour justement dire `mélanger` et ce, même de la part de gens que je considère comme ayant un "haut" niveau d'éducation.

Au cas où, j'ai grandi en Haute-Savoie donc il s'agit peut-être d'argot, bien que ça me semble peu probable dans la mesure où j'ai entendu des gens venant d'autres régions de France employer ce sens à l'oral.

Comment: Personnellement j'utilise "brasser" pour "mélanger" uniquement quand on parle de quantités relativement importantes. Si je prépare une bolognaise à la maison, je vais sûrement la mélanger. Si je la prépare pour une bande de scouts, il est possible que j'emploie le terme "brasser".  Je n'ai jamais considéré cela comme particulièrement familier.

Answer (score 2):

D'après ce que l'un de plusieurs sens apparemment très bien établis, qui se vérifient dans un dictionnaire, c'est un très bon choix de synonyme ;

Ce que les personnes déconseillant cet usage ont à l'esprit est le sens premier du verbe ;

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brasser)) A. Fabriquer de la bière en opérant à chaud le mélange du malt et de l'eau. Brasser la bière, le moût

Ce dont ils ne sont pas conscient, c'est que le verbe a acquis par analogie des sens voisins les uns des autres et qui ne sont pas du tout spécialisés à la fabrication de la bière ;

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brasser)) B. P. anal.¹
>
> 1. Agiter, remuer une substance ou un mélange à température élevée :
> 2. Agiter, remuer, retourner, malaxer quelque chose en vue de résultats divers.
>
>    - Son pied a heurté par malchance le seau dans lequel on brasse la bouillie de son pour les poules.  (BERNANOS, Nouvelle Hist. de Mouchette, 1937, p. 1298)
>
> a) En partic. Malaxer, pétrir, remuer.

Le sens numéro 2 me parait convenir très bien pour décrire le processus de mélanger des ingrédients culinaires. Le résultat particulier dans le cas de la nourriture qui passe sur la table est celui d'obtenir un mélange. Ces personnes que vous jugez comme ayant un solide niveau d'éducation ne se trompent donc pas sur cet usage qu'elles en font ; il ne s'agit pas d'argot ni d'un terme familier mais il serait probablement peu employé ainsi. Personnellement, je ne suis pas du tout habitué à l'entendre dans le contexte des ingrédients prêts à manger  et ne l'ai jamais employé pour cela mais dès que je l'ai lu dans votre texte j'ai pu identifier le concept approximativement et je crois que je n'aurais jamais douté la pertinence de son usage vu que je suis habitué à le trouver dans toutes sortes d'autres contextes étranger à la bière. Néanmoins, c'est un usage qui me semble un peu bizarre pour les liquides, et il serait possiblement plus adéquat pour les matières à consistance de pâte ou de crème épaisse (brasser des cocktails peut-être), mais  je crois  que ce n'est qu'impression, c'est très subjectif.

¹<sub>« P. anal. » devrait signifier « par analogie » ; « B. » pourrait signifier « Bien », mais il n'y a pas de certitude, cette abréviation-ci ne figure pas dans la liste des abréviations du TLFi.</sub>

On trouve une application très productive de ce verbe dans un emploi par métaphore ou au figuré ;

brasser les X

- les idées
- les populations (les faire tendre au métissage (mélange))
- les peuples
- les affaires

Comment: "Application tres productive, indeed!  On peut meme "brasser s/les camarades" figurativement (see https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21946)

Comment: Vous utiliser presque toujours le TLFi pour vos réponses. Est-il (si vous me permettez) la bible des dictionnaires de la langue française ? Sans erreur de ma part il n'a pas été actualisé depuis les années 1990s. 25 ans d'évolution de la langue française et d'interaction avec d'autres langues sont entièrement manques, n'est-ce pas ? Pourquoi ne consultez-vous pas d'autres ressources contemporaines et disponibles en ligne ?

Comment: @Dimitris Le TLFi est un excellent dictionnaire, du moins pour qui sait lire. Il lui manque bien sûr quelques évolutions/apparitions lexicales et d'autres sources sont souvent utiles, mais il ne faut pas jeter le bébé avec l'eau du bain !

Comment: @Dimitris C'est une question que je ne peux expédier en quelques mots ; c'est toute une discussion qui prendrait facilement plusieurs champs à commentaire entiers. J'utilise essentiellement le TLFi mais j'ai quand même recours aux dictionnaire suivants assez souvent : Wiktionaire, Internaute, reverso,  WordReference, Linguee,…et quelques autres dont je ne me souviens pas.

Comment: @personne Il y a bien un trait, mais à la copie c'est de la mise en forme qui disparait ; de plus voilà encore du symbolisme pour lequel on ne trouve d'explications nulle part. L'interface n'a pas d'importance du point de vue information et présentation, lesquelles sont strictement les mêmes du moins pour les interfaces que je connais et qui sont au nombre de  deux ; j'utilise la première pour ses capacités  de recherche des expressions dans le TLFi (http://atilf.atilf.fr/) ; (champ 1)

Comment: @personne  j'utilise la seconde (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) pour établir les liens informatiques aux mots que je vérifie, cela en raison de l'impossibilité de le faire avec la première, qui produit toujours des liens morts.

Comment: Mais oui mais la note 1 est inutile, généralement t'as un ordre avec une séquence, soit du plus usuel au moins usuel, soit, comme c'est le cas avec _brasser_, on commence avec le sens au propre, puis on a les sens par analogie, puis au figuré, les lettres et les chiffres ne servent qu'à présenter l'information et n'ont pas besoin de faire l'objet de conventions spécifiques, surtout quand ils sont suivis d'un nom de rubrique, et sont même inutiles dans ta réponse. Par ailleurs une autre solution consiste à simplement écrire _par analogie_ quand tu rencontres p. anal. etc. dans le TLFi.

Answer (score 1):

Non locuteur natif mais je vais essayer de répondre. En fait, selon le  [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasser) il existe deux verbes avec la même orthographe.

> (Verbe 1) Du gaulois bracis, passé au latin populaire *braciare, de
> braces (« blé blanc, malt »), apparenté à braise (« drêche »), brai.
> Le sens étymologique est proche de « (faire) fermenter ». Il a subi
> l’influence sémantique de bras dans certains de ses sens. La véritable
> orthographe serait non brasser, puisque le mot ne vient pas de bras,
> mais bracer, comme on l'écrivait autrefois[1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasser).
>
> (Verbe 2) Dénominal de bras ou brasse.

Le premier a plusieurs sens, entre autres :

> (Par analogie) Mouvoir, agiter en vue d’une opération.
>
> Brasser du métal, des cuirs, des épingles, des clous.

et

> (Jeux) Mélanger des cartes ou tout autre objet.
>
> Brasser les cartes, les dés, les feuilles.

Le second en a deux,

> (Marine) Mouvoir les bras d’une vergue pour changer la direction de la voile qu’elle porte.
>
> Nager la brasse.

Avec ce méli-mélo d'emplois et de définitions, il me semble logique que tout le monde ne connaisse pas tous les sens.

Il existe même un sens un peu argotique :

> Ce bâtard il a brassé avec son album, il a fait 20 000 ventes la première semaine.
>
> Brasser est un verbe désignant le fait de faire de l’argent, de manière légale ou non.

Source : http://www.urbandico.com/definition/brasser/