# Le « saur » du hareng qui le fait incidemment « d'un jaune qui tire sur le brun » : autres exemples etc. ?

Tags: usage, étymologie, latin, néerlandais, zoologie

On a le [*hareng saur*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hareng_saur), le poisson [*salé/fumé*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saur/2), ayant subi le [saurissage](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/saurissage/71164?q=saurissage#70392), dans le domaine agroalimentaire, par emprunt au moyen néerlandais [*soor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/saur) « (bois, hareng) séché » (TLFi ; voir aussi [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/saure)) ; enfin on comprend le rôle de la ficelle dans le [poème](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Hareng_saur) de Charles Cros du même nom. Le francique [*saur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/saur/1), « d'un jaune qui tire sur le brun », y serait soit apparenté, soit apparenté au bas latin *saura* (peut-être utilisé pour gloser *roux* dans des [descriptions](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/229992) ; voir ds. *Roland* [texte](https://archive.org/stream/lachansonderolan00bduoft#page/148/mode/2up), [manuscrit](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Chanson_de_Roland/Manuscrit_d%E2%80%99Oxford/Page_70) : *Li Marganices sist sur un ceval sor*,) ou [*saurus*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/229996) (désignant des noms de poissons ; *DHLF/Rey* parle du rapprochement que fait Guiraud avec la base latine *saur-* qu'on trouve dans les dérivés en bas latin, et qui sert à « désigner des animaux à couleur mêlée de brun »). Il y a aussi des [applications](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=saure&dicoid=NICOT1606) dans d'autres langues romanes. En résumé on a le hareng et la polysémie du *saur* avec possiblement le même étymon commun à tous. Voici deux *harengs saurs*, et le hareng est à l'origine azur avant son traitement, de sorte que le *saur* l'aura rendu *saur*, pour ainsi dire :

[image]
 <sup><sup>Image : Christopher Bertram (user: bristoleast) tirée de [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Buckling.jpg).</sup></sup>

Ce glissement n'est pas sans évoquer le genre de transformation [étrange](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26879) qu'on peut trouver en héraldique avec le [blasonnement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasonnement), par exemple avec l'histoire de la couleur [*sable*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sable/1) : c'est que la fourrure de zibeline ([russe](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/226747)/polonais *sobol'*), normalement blanche, et bien on avait l'habitude de la teindre en noir ! Et donc ça veut dire noir dans ce contexte-là... C'est un emploi spécialisé, et non une concurrence usuelle avec la couleur qu'on pourrait associer au sable ([beige clair](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sable)).

---

- L'acception de *saur* pour la couleur *(jaune) tirant sur/mêlée de brun* est-elle connue aujourd'hui généralement, est-ce d'un registre particulier ; le fait que ce soit plus ou moins réservé à la couleur d'un animal bien connu ou à des emplois spécialisés, que ça apparaisse dans l'œuvre de Cros ou avec le hareng généralement, qu'est-ce que ça permettrait de dire au sujet de l'usage/la perception qu'on fait/a de ce mot aujourd'hui ?
- Connaît-on d'autres mots composés, plutôt figés, qui contiennent un nom qui peut référer à une couleur inusitée, ou qui n'est plus généralement sentie comme une couleur usuellement, différemment du [vert-de-gris](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vert-de-gris), et plutôt tel que le *saur* du *hareng saur* peut l'être (on exclura le [*ti-caille*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13149), du Québec) ?
- Y a-t-il des exemples en français de mots basés sur [*saur-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saur-) qui
  témoigneraient de la couleur particulière dont on vient de discuter
  plutôt que (de celle) du lézard/des mots [savants](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saurien) qui semblent l'avoir supplantée, et qui illustreraient en français la conséquence du propos de P. Guiraud mentionné au DHLF ?

Answer (score 2):

Une réponse partielle seulement...

Je ne crois pas que *saur* pour la couleur soit courant de nos jours en France. Il est même possible que seul usage de *saur* aujourd'hui soit dans ... *hareng saur*. Si on jouait aux jeux des associations automatiques de mots, *saur* déclencherait *hareng* à coup sûr. La preuve par [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_NOUN%20saur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_NOUN%20saur%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhareng_NOUN%20saur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHareng_NOUN%20saur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bqu%27il_NOUN%20saur%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: Merci ! Savez-vous si le poème de Cros fait partie du curriculum au BAC ou s'il est bien connu en général en France ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas. Cela dépend sans doute du professeur. Je ne l'ai pas appris pour ma part. L'auteur ne m'était pas familier.

Comment: De mon côté, _saur_ me fait toujours penser à un vieillard, à celui qui eut ce mot malheureux dans _Le camp des Croisés_ (1838), pièce d’Alphonse Dumas: _«J’en sortirai du camp, mais quel que soit mon sort / J’aurai montré du moins comme un vieillard en sort!»_. Je ne nierai pas que le hareng a joué un rôle primordial dans l’immortalisation de ces deux vers, mais le vieillard pour moi a complètement supplanté son image. :~)